# Oracle in DB First Entity Framework Core maps NUMBER(3) to byte causes runtime exception

Tags: c#, oracle, types, orm, entity-framework-core

I am working on a on-going project which consists with an existing Oracle DB. Recently, we are plannig to restructure our backend code and have taken EF Core as our DAL backbone. Everything works fine before. However, we encountered an issue just now.

Oracle in EF Core keeps mapping entity's column type with `NUMBER(3)` to `byte` as a model. As `NUMBER(3)` can hold number up to 999 while `byte` is only capable up to `256`. Therefore, value with >256 makes runtime error thrown.

I am using `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate model classes, each `Scaffold-DbContext` will clear up all my data model and regenerating again according to the current DB table schemas. Eventually, manually update the model's data type is not a solution for me. Anyone can help me out on how to map `NUMBER(3)` to `int`/`double` permenantly without being overwritten by each `Scaffold-DbContext`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is ODP mapping configuration that you can use in app.config. But the problem, it will affect the entire system, not 1 table/column.

Comment: @T.S. Does ODP mapping configuration works in .NET core version?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/entityDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-8EE05F96-7262-4804-A713-EAF190303DBD

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/InstallODPCore.html#GUID-6A865B77-99D7-4F5E-A19B-4D7CC4F56885

Comment: @T.S. The first link you referred to is the edm mapping for .NET Framework and those configs are for `app.config` which does not capable for .NET Core. The second link you referred is just the installation procedure of ODP .NET Core version. Seems they are unrelated. Have you tried this solution and if it works?

Comment: app.config IS working with .net core. Microsoft released package for that, so you can use `app.config`, `ConfigurationManager` as usual, in .net core. https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.configuration.configurationmanager/

Comment: *"Fluent APIs/Annotations can be used to map the .NET types to any valid Oracle data type."* https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-484E9D3A-8E42-417F-9591-F2E7305E3F6A

Comment: How come I can find all these things ^^^ online and you can't?